# VBA Listview Set and Get with column name

Tags: excel, vba, listview

I am trying to populate a `RecordSet` into a `ListView` in VBA.
The idea is to add the column name as key so I also can access later the element by  the name

Here is how I fill the `Listview`. I want to show only one column but keep the rest of properties with column width 0:

```
rs.MoveFirst
Dim fieldCounter As Integer
Dim columnWidth  As Integer
With lstProgram
    .View = lvwReport
    .Gridlines = True
    .FullRowSelect = True
    For fieldCounter = 0 To rs.Fields.count - 1
        columnWidth = 300
        If fieldCounter <> 0 Then
            columnWidth = 0
        End If
        .ColumnHeaders.Add fieldCounter + 1, rs.Fields(fieldCounter).Name, _
            rs.Fields(fieldCounter).Name, columnWidth
    Next fieldCounter
    Do
        If Not (IsNull(rs.Fields(0).value)) Then
            Dim tmpItem As ListItem
            For fieldCounter = 1 To rs.Fields.count
                If fieldCounter = 1 Then
                    Set tmpItem = .listItems.Add(, , rs.Fields(fieldCounter - 1).value)
                Else
                    If Not IsNull(rs.Fields(fieldCounter - 1).value) Then
                        tmpItem.ListSubItems.Add text:=rs.Fields(fieldCounter - 1).value
                    Else
                        tmpItem.ListSubItems.Add text:=""
                    End If
                End If
            Next fieldCounter
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
End With
```

Then I would like to do something like this:

```
Private Sub DisplayProgramItem(ByVal Item As MSComctlLib.ListItem)
On Error GoTo error
    txtOpexID.text = Item.ListSubItems("OPEXID")
    txtName.text = Item.text
    cmbCluster.text = Item.ListSubItems("Cluster")
done:
   Exit Sub
error:
   ErrNotify Err, Me.Name, "lstProgram_ItemClick"
   Resume done
End Sub
```

Any Idea how to achieve this?

I found some interesting links but none of them solve my problem I think or at least I couldn't fix the issue of duplicated key when I try

`Set tmpItem = .listItems.Add(,rs.Fields(fieldCounter - 1).Name, rs.Fields(fieldCounter - 1).value)`

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b96f9fbe-e128-4b49-833d-2a5f6e678dae/access-listview-subitem-text-by-column-header?forum=winforms

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-us/6ed95bf8-6e37-4306-87a6-2267dd83c1d1/refer-to-listview-subitems-by-name?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: Listview is not supported in a 64 bit environment so it isn't a future proof choice. Use listbox instead. To answer your question: why don't you simply use constants to refer to columns? Or you can even use vars if you want to make it dynamic.  Your example could look like `txtOpexID.text = .List(<row>, OPEXID)` where `<row>` identifies the row, `OPEXID` identifies the column of the element.

Comment: I tried to use `listbox` but it has a limitation in the number of columns it can carry and my recordset is bigger. Using Constants could be a solution. I have to check and adjust a couple of dynamically generated components.